# Difficult example of functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives

give an example of two functions: $g$ discontinuous at $t_0$, and f continuous but not derivable at $g(t_0)$ so that $f\circ g$ is derivable at $t_0$

Do this two functions exist? I would appreciate your help :)

Comment: You mean differentiable.

Comment: Be advised, I've deleted my answer since I found I flaw in it. Oops.

Comment: Is that $fog$ meant to be $f\circ g$?

Comment: @orion, edited.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=|x^2-1|,$$
$$g(x)=\chi_{\Bbb Q}-\chi_{\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q},$$
$$t_0=0,$$
$g$ is discontinuous in $t_0$ (and in any point of $\Bbb R$), $g(0)=1$.

$f$ is continuous in $\Bbb R$, nondifferentiable at $\pm1$ and
$$\forall x\in\Bbb R:\  f\circ g(x)=0.$$

Comment: Simplification:$f(x):=|x|$.

Comment: $g(0)=1$ and absvalue is differentiable at 1.